# ORACLE: how to find all dependencies of objects of a column in a specific table

Tags: oracle, data-dictionary

i,d like to know a way of make a query where i can find all dependencies of objects with a specific column in a specific table. 
I can do it with a table but i dont know how to do it with a column of that table

```
SELECT   type,
           name
    FROM   user_dependencies
   WHERE   referenced_name = 'table_name'
ORDER BY   type,
           name
```

Comment: check user_source

Comment: If you're using Oracle 12.2 or later then you can get this information through PL/SCOPE. [Find out more](https://www.salvis.com/blog/2017/03/17/plscope-utils-utilities-for-plscope-in-oracle-database-12-2/)

Answer (score 1):

user_dependencies and user_source dictionar views may be joined to get the pieces in which `mytable`'s `col0` exists :

```
SELECT d.type, d.name, s.line as line_number, s.text
  FROM user_dependencies d
  LEFT JOIN user_source s
    ON s.name = d.name
 WHERE d.referenced_name = 'MYTABLE'
   AND upper(s.text) like '%COL0%'
 ORDER BY d.type, d.name
```

To search through the whole DB (provided the privileges exist)

```
SELECT d.type, d.name, s.line as line_number, s.text
  FROM dba_dependencies d
  LEFT JOIN dba_source s
    ON s.name = d.name
 WHERE d.referenced_name = 'MYTABLE'
   AND upper(s.text) like '%COL0%'
 ORDER BY d.type, d.name
```

Note that : In fact `mytable.*` implicitly contains also your desired column.